# Cómo dar valor a un atributo dentro de un diccionario que a su vez esta dentro de otro diccionario?

Tags: python, xml, lista, diccionarios, get

Aqui os dejo mi codigo donde se intento sacar valores de atributos de un archivo XML. Para ello me he creado un diccionario con las etiquetas del archivo y luego le he introducido a su vez un diccionario con los nombres de atributos y el valor iniciado en vacio. Mi problema llega a la hora de dar valor con el comando attrs.get a la posicion a la que quiero acceder de mi diccionario. Si encuentran algun otro error le agradezco me ayudaran.

```
from xml.sax import make_parser
from xml.sax.handler import ContentHandler

class SmallSMILHandler(ContentHandler):

    def __init__ (self):

        atb_rootlayout = {"width":"","height":"","background-color":""}
        atb_region = {"id":"","top":"","bottom":"", "left":"", "right":""}
        atb_img = {"src":"", "region":"", "begin":"", "dur":""}
        atb_audio = {"src":"", "begin":"", "dur":""}
        atb_textstream = {"src":"", "region":""}
        self.etiquetas ={"root-layout": atb_rootlayout,"region": atb_region,
                         "img": atb_img,"audio": atb_audio, 
                         "textstream": atb_textstream}        
        self.datos = []

    def inEtiqueta(self, name, attrs):

        if name in self.etiquetas:

            for atb in self.etiquetas[name]:
                self.etiquetas[name][atb] = attrs.get(atb, "") 

    def get_tags (self):

        print(self.etiquetas)



if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = make_parser()
    cHandler = SmallSMILHandler()
    parser.setContentHandler(cHandler)
    parser.parse(open('karaoke.smil'))    
    cHandler.get_tags()
```

Os añado el contenido del archivo 'karaoke.smil'

```
<smil>
  <head>
    <layout> <!--Create the canvas and two display regions -->
        <root-layout width="248" height="300"
        background-color="blue" />
         <region id="a" top="20" left="64" />
         <region id="b" top="120" left="20"/>
         <region id="text_area" top="100" left="20"/>
     </layout>
  </head>
  <body>
     <par>
    <img src="http://www.content-networking.com/smil/hello.jpg"
         region="a"
         begin="2s"
         dur="36s"/> <!--Display "Hello" image now for 6 seconds -->
    <img src="http://www.content-networking.com/smil/earthrise.jpg"
         region="b"
         begin="12s"
         end="48s"/> <!--Display the "World" image after 12 seconds -->
    <audio src="http://www.content-networking.com/smil/hello.wav"
         begin="1s"/> <!-- Begin the audio after 1 seconds -->
    <textstream src="http://gsyc.es/~grex/letra.rt" region="text_area" fill="freeze" />
        <audio src="cancion.ogg" begin="4s"/>
    </par>
  </body>
</smil>
```

Comment: Según entiendo tu pregunta, dices tener problemas al acceder _para escribir_ la etiqueta anidada. Es decir, entiendo que la línea que te da problemas es `self.etiquetas[name][atb] = ...` Sin embargo esa línea está bien y en un [experimento que acabo de hacer](https://repl.it/@abul4fia/RequiredDimpledUsers) con un código reducido funciona correctamente. ¿Qué error encuentras exactamente? ¿Una excepción o que no se guardan los valores que esperabas? ¿Será que el problema está en el `attrs.get(atb,"")` que no encuentra ese campo?

Comment: @abulafia el problema es que no me salta ningun error. Yo entiendo que la sintaxis esta bien hecha pero como bien dices el comando attrs.get es el que debe estar fallando. Con este programa pretendo leer un fichero .smil en el que al leerme la etiqueta correspondiente, mire el atributo correspondiente y extraiga el valor y lo escriba dentro del diccionario en la posicion adecuada

Comment: @FJSevilla he metido el comando que me has facilitado pero tampoco me añade ningun valor al diccionario self.etiquetas que es el que debo imprimir al final con los valores extraidos del documento

Comment: Victor agrega el contenido del archivo `karaoke.smil` o al menos un ejemplo mínimo del mismo que reproduzca el problema, a ver si reproduciendo el código damos con lo que pasa.

Comment: @FJSevilla ya he añadido el contenido del archivo .smil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente tu error es que el método `inEtiqueta()` nunca es invocado (ya su nombre hace sospechar que no es un *handler* válido).

Mirando la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.sax.handler.html#contenthandler-objects) de `xml.sax.handler`  se observa que el método que se invoca cuando se "entra" en un tag es `startElement()`. Cambiando el nombre de tu método `inEtiqueta()` a `startElement()` ya funciona.

La salida que produce es:

```
{'audio': {'begin': '4s', 'dur': '', 'src': 'cancion.ogg'},
 'img': {'begin': '12s',
  'dur': '',
  'region': 'b',
  'src': 'http://www.content-networking.com/smil/earthrise.jpg'},
 'region': {'bottom': '',
  'id': 'text_area',
  'left': '20',
  'right': '',
  'top': '100'},
 'root-layout': {'background-color': 'blue', 'height': '300', 'width': '248'},
 'textstream': {'region': 'text_area', 'src': 'http://gsyc.es/~grex/letra.rt'}}
```

#### Actualización

Si comparamos el diccionario producido al ejecutar el programa con el SMIL de entrada vemos un problema: cuando un mismo tag (por ejemplo `region`) se repite en el SMIL, el código irá sobreescribiendo la misma entrada `self.etiquetas[name]`. Al final sólo tendremos el contenido del último tag, o un mix raro si cada vez que aparece ese `name` no se repiten exactamente los mismos tags.

A falta de comprender mejor el contexto en que se va a utilizar esto, creo que una solución mejor sería que cada `name` almacene, en lugar de un diccionario, una lista de diccionarios. La lista tendría tantos elementos como veces se repita ese tag en el smil. Así por ejemplo, ya que `region` aparece tres veces en el smil, `self.etiquetas["region"]` sería una lista con tres diccionarios.

Para implementar esto hay que separar el diccionario que originalmente se usaba a modo de plantilla para definir qué atributos nos interesan de cada tag, del diccionario de resultados. Es decir, tendremos dos variables.

Si dejamos `self.etiquetas` para su cometido original (hacer de "plantilla"), crearemos otra `self.resultado` para guardar el resultado del *parsing*.

Haré uso de `defaultdict` para simplificar y no tener que distinguir entre cuándo un "name" aparece por primera vez (en cuyo caso habría que crear una lista vacía para meter en ella el diccionario correspondiente) de cuándo ya apareció antes (en cuyo caso hay que añadir a la lista pre-existente el nuevo diccionario). Gracias a `defaultdict` el código es como si la lista ya estuviera creada antes (y `defaultdict` se ocupa de crear una vacía si no es así).

Este es el código adaptado a esta situación:

```
from xml.sax import make_parser
from xml.sax.handler import ContentHandler
from collections import defaultdict

class SmallSMILHandler(ContentHandler):

    def __init__ (self):
        atb_rootlayout = {"width":"","height":"","background-color":""}
        atb_region = {"id":"","top":"","bottom":"", "left":"", "right":""}
        atb_img = {"src":"", "region":"", "begin":"", "dur":""}
        atb_audio = {"src":"", "begin":"", "dur":""}
        atb_textstream = {"src":"", "region":""}
        self.etiquetas ={"root-layout": atb_rootlayout,"region": atb_region,
                         "img": atb_img,"audio": atb_audio, 
                         "textstream": atb_textstream}

        self.resultado = defaultdict(list)

    def startElement(self, name, attrs):
        if name in self.etiquetas:
            data = {}  # Diccionoario interno a crear para esta etiqueta
            for atb in self.etiquetas[name]:
                data[atb] = attrs.get(atb, "") 
            # Una vez creado el diccionario interno, lo añadimos a esta clave
            self.resultado[name].append(data)

    def get_tags (self):
        return dict(self.resultado)

parser = make_parser()
cHandler = SmallSMILHandler()
parser.setContentHandler(cHandler)
parser.parse(open('karaoke.smil'))    
r = cHandler.get_tags()
print(r)
```

Ahora el resultado es:

```
{'audio': [{'begin': '1s',
   'dur': '',
   'src': 'http://www.content-networking.com/smil/hello.wav'},
  {'begin': '4s', 'dur': '', 'src': 'cancion.ogg'}],
 'img': [{'begin': '2s',
   'dur': '36s',
   'region': 'a',
   'src': 'http://www.content-networking.com/smil/hello.jpg'},
  {'begin': '12s',
   'dur': '',
   'region': 'b',
   'src': 'http://www.content-networking.com/smil/earthrise.jpg'}],
 'region': [{'bottom': '', 'id': 'a', 'left': '64', 'right': '', 'top': '20'},
  {'bottom': '', 'id': 'b', 'left': '20', 'right': '', 'top': '120'},
  {'bottom': '', 'id': 'text_area', 'left': '20', 'right': '', 'top': '100'}],
 'root-layout': [{'background-color': 'blue',
   'height': '300',
   'width': '248'}],
 'textstream': [{'region': 'text_area',
   'src': 'http://gsyc.es/~grex/letra.rt'}]}
```

Observa cómo todos los valores del diccionario son listas (en muchos casos con un solo elemento, pero en algunos casos con dos o tres). Cada elemento es un diccionario con los atributos elegidos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, ahora ya funciona "casi" como debe funcionar

Comment: @VictorCorreaRuiz Creo que entiendo a qué te refieres. Si el SMIL contiene varios tags `img`, o `region`, etc.. tu diccionario se queda sólo con el último (o de hecho quizás con un mix de atributos). Creo que tu diccionario principal debería guardar para cada clave una lista de diccionarios, en lugar de otro diccionario. Si quieres extiendo la respuesta para mostrarte una forma de hacerlo.

Comment: si puedes extendermela para verlo claramente ayudaría a entenderlo

Comment: @VictorCorreaRuiz Hecho!

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, y gracias por la aclaración en la actualización. Un saludo!